# Problem with the top position of the sidebar

Tags: html, css, browser, navigation, sidebar

I need help with this sidebar. It does not want to be placed at the beginning of the top edge. ( It protrudes a few millimeters from the top) It looks like: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoaX0.jpg).

```
CSS CODE:
https://pastebin.com/RUmsRkYw


HTML CODE:
https://pastebin.com/GsLHx15d
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your code. You have to add top and bottom

```
.sidebar_container{
    position: fixed;
    width: 220px;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #303030;
    color: #fff;
}
```